# clipsToBounds with CGAffineTransformRotate problems

Tags: iphone, rotation, masking

I have an UIView with a UIImageView as the subview. UIImageView size is always larger than the UIView, so i set clipsToBounds = YES to the UIView, user can drag the UIImageView. Just imagine it is a PhotoFrame, UIView = Frame, UIImageView = Photo.

But after i use CGAffineTransformRotate, i found that the UIView is not actually 100% rotate.
As you see from the screenshot, the black border is belong to the UIView with clipsToBounds = YES, UIImageView is rotated. But the clipsToBounds effect is not rotated.

This is the screenshot link http://www.flickr.com/photos/66833422@N02/6585836809/

My question is:
Any solution so that i can rotate the effect of clipsToBounds? I tried masksToBounds, and the result is still the same.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, can any one having solution for it

Answer (score 0):

I just spent ~10 hours trying to figure out the same problem. I think I've got a hacky solution. Basically, wrap the image in two UIViews, and set clipsToBounds = YES on both.

Your view hierarchy should look like

UIView (extra view)

. UIView (image container view)

. . UIImageView

The extra view and the image container view should have the same size and clipsToBounds = YES. The CGAffineTransform should be applied to the extra view.